# Define a dynamic class name in the DOM with SCSS

Tags: sass

My wish is to have something like that directly in the DOM ( `class` attr )

```
<a class="padding-left-30"> Link 1 </a>
<a class="padding-right-15"> Link 1 </a>
```

w/o defining a strict class for it ( i.e: `style="padding-left: 30px"` or same in `style.css` )

And I was trying to do something simple like this:

```
@mixin .padding-#{$direction}-#{$px} {
    padding-#{$direction}: #{$px}px;
}
```

But it gives me an error of:

```
invalid name in @mixin definition
```

Any idea how to adjust it ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make two maps with the properties you want to mix.
2. For each combination create a placeholder class. I think it's appropiate if you don't want to create a full list of classes that maybe you won't use. This is the modular-friendly use.
3. Extend the class in your element.

   ```
   $paddingDirection:('right','left','top','bottom');
   $paddingLength:(15,30,45,50);

   @each $dir in $paddingDirection{
     @each $len in $paddingLength{
       %padding-#{$dir}-#{$len}{ padding-#{$dir}: #{$len}px;}
     }
   }

   .padding-right-30{
     @extend %padding-right-30;
   }

   /*output*/
   .padding-right-30 {
      padding-right: 30px;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's exactly what I didn't want to do ... otherwise I'll keep adding all kinds of paddings in the `$paddingLength` making 4 rows for a single padding-px ... :/ any other thoughts ?

Comment: That's why placeholder class `%` exists. You avoid making any row, but you can use them if you need.

Comment: Yeah ... not 100% sure still, because instead of all of this code `.padding-right-30{  @extend %padding-right-30; }` I can simply say `.padding-right-30 { padding-right: 30px }` .. extending it - doesn't really reduce my code, no ?

Comment: Use it anywhere like: `.any-class{@extend %padding-right-30;}` and you avoid creating extra classes.