# Dynamic margin/padding with sass

Tags: css, sass

Is it  possible to simplify and make this more easily maintained with sass?

```
.padding-8 { padding: 8px !important; }
.padding-10 { padding: 10px !important; }

.padding-top-0 { padding-top: 0 !important; }
.padding-top-3 { padding-top: 3px !important; }

.padding-bottom-0 { padding-bottom: 0 !important; }
.padding-bottom-3 { padding-bottom: 3px !important; }
.padding-bottom-5 { padding-bottom: 5px !important; }

.margin-top-0 { margin-top: 0 !important; }
.margin-top-5 { margin-top: 5px !important; }

.margin-bottom-0 { margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
.margin-bottom-5 { margin-bottom: 5px !important; }
```

etc..

Is it also possible to write something like `.padding-$dir-$value { padding-$dir: $value px !important; }` so you can use a class with f.ex padding-left-13?

Comment: Why would you want this? Writing something like: `padding-left-13` will exactly be the same as writing it the normal way: `padding-left: 13px;`. A function like this won't improve readability of your code and you will reduce maintainability. If not for you it will for other developers.

Comment: then I would have to add a style="padding-left: 13px;" to the elements instead of just adding it to the class tag

Comment: Right. And the elements won't have other styles?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make two maps with the properties you want to mix.
2. For each combination create a placeholder class. I think it's appropiate if you don't want to create a full list of classes that maybe you won't use. This is the modular-friendly use.
3. Extend the class in your element.

   ```
   $paddingDirection:('right','left','top','bottom');
   $paddingLength:(15,30,45,50);

   @each $dir in $paddingDirection{
     @each $len in $paddingLength{
       %padding-#{$dir}-#{$len}{ padding-#{$dir}: #{$len}px;}
     }
   }

   .any-class{
     @extend %padding-right-30;
   }

   /*output*/
   .any-class {
      padding-right: 30px;
   }
   ```

> Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261759/define-a-dynamic-class-name-in-the-dom-with-scss/44267344#44267344)

Comment: Hmm don't quite get it. Doesn't the loop on the top create the css classes? I still have to add a class for each .padding-right-30 { extend ...} and another for f.ex .padding-right-15 { extend ... } etc?

Comment: No and no: The loop create placeholder classes, there are not applied to the output stylesheet. I am going to edit it to make it clearer but use directly `.any-class{@extend padding-left-30;}`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this: (enhanced the above solution)

```
$paddingDirection:('right','left','top','bottom');
$paddingLength:(15,30,45,50);
// if you only wants to use "padding" without postfix
@each $len in $paddingLength {
  .padding-#{$len} { padding: #{$len}px;}
}

// if you want to use padding-left, padding-right etc.
@each $dir in $paddingDirection {
  @each $len in $paddingLength {
    .padding-#{$dir}-#{$len} { padding-#{$dir}: #{$len}px;}
  }
}

usage:
<div class="padding-15"></div>
<div class="padding-left-15 padding-top-15"></div>
```